# How to load bitmap into canvas and draw freely with finger over bitmap?

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to figure out how to load a bitmap into canvas and draw over it. I tried but drawing over bitmap not working instead it was drawing beneath bitmap(which i saw after) Below my code is given. Thank you in advance, need help as i'm new to android.
Normal drawing is working and the drawing is also getting saved on clicking save button.But edit is not working, i tried but not working.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
public static int BRUSH_SIZE=18;
public static int ERASER_SIZE=25;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR= Color.BLACK;
public static final int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR= Color.WHITE;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE= 4;
private float pointX,pointY;
private Path path;
private Paint paint;
private ArrayList<FingerPath> pathsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<FingerPath> redoList = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor=DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private Bitmap bitmap,bitmapToEdit,nBmp,canvasBitmap;
private Canvas canvas;
private Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
private int lastPath;
private boolean editMode;
Realm mRealm;
byte[] imgBytes; 

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    path=new Path();
    paint=new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics){
    if(editMode)
        startNew();
    else {
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }
    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void startNew(){
    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    nBmp=bitmapToEdit.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(nBmp,0,0,paint);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    Log.e("size changed","called");
    bitmapToEdit=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvasBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    nBmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas=new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

}

public void editImage(Bitmap gotbitmap){
    editMode=true;
    bitmapToEdit=gotbitmap;
}

public void save(Context context){
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap saveBitmap=getDrawingCache();
    imgBytes=new byte[0];
    mRealm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    if(saveBitmap!=null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        saveBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,50,stream);
        imgBytes=stream.toByteArray();
        final Drawing drawingObj=new Drawing();
        mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Number currentNum=mRealm.where(Drawing.class).maximumInt("id");
                Log.e("currentNum",String.valueOf(currentNum));
                int nextId;
                if(currentNum==null){
                    nextId=1;
                }else{
                    nextId=currentNum.intValue()+1;
                }
                Log.e("nextId",String.valueOf(nextId));
                drawingObj.setId(nextId);
                drawingObj.setImage(imgBytes);
                mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(drawingObj);
                Log.e("imgBytes",imgBytes.toString());
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(context,"Image saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        destroyDrawingCache();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Image not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(editMode){
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,0,0,bitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
    }else {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
        for (FingerPath fp : pathsList) {
            paint.setColor(fp.color);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
            canvas.drawPath(fp.path, paint);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

//This function used when initial touch on screen
private void touchStart(float x,float y){
    redoList.clear();
    path = new Path();
    FingerPath fingerPath = new FingerPath(currentColor,strokeWidth,path);
    pathsList.add(fingerPath);
    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(x,y);
    pointX=x;
    pointY=y;
}

//This function used when keeping finger down and moving on screen
private void touchMove(float x,float y){
    float dx = Math.abs(x - pointX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - pointY);
    if(dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE){
        path.quadTo(pointX,pointY,(x + pointX)/2,(y + pointY)/2);
        pointX=x;
        pointY=y;
    }
}

//This function used when after drawing, finger is removed from the screen
private void touchUp(){
    path.lineTo(pointX,pointY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    if(editMode){
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(x,y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(x,y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
                path.reset();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
    else{
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share enough code to set up a small sample in order to reproduce the problem. I'd like to debug the View while drawing and I've no idea which would be the correct order for the various public methods to be called

Comment: Well, when `editMode` is false, you're drawing the bitmap after you draw the paths. That's going to put the bitmap on top.

Comment: @greeble31 It was really a silly mistake. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When `editMode` is false, you're drawing the bitmap after you draw the paths. That's going to put the bitmap on top. To fix, put the `canvas.drawBitmap()` call right after the `canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)` call :)